# Was there a Soreg in Bayit Rishon?

Tags: gentiles, beis-hamikdash

I understand there was a little fence in Bayit Sheni called "HaSoreg"/"The Grille" which was meant to warn away gentiles and tme'im from entering the Chayil part of Har Habayit (according to the mishna in [Kelim 1:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Kelim.1.8?lang=en&with=Bartenura&lang2=en) and commentaries such as [the Bartenura](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Kelim.1.8?lang=en&with=Bartenura&lang2=en) who mentions Shaar Nikanor which was only in Bayit Sheni) (just on a side-note, a couple of the Soreg's signs were found by archaeologists, as can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Warning_inscription)). Was there such a thing in Bayit Rishon? And if not, why?