Where couldn't the gentiles go in Solomon's Temple?
I would like to know where were gentiles not allowed to go in Solomon's Temple. Was there a court for Gentiles like the Second Temple? Could they enter any of the courts in Solomon's Temple? Many thanks.

For second temple at least, there was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_Warning_inscription

It appears that the Halochos of [public] ritual purity were established only in the Hasmonean period (late 2nd century BCE). E.g. we don't find evidence for Mikvas before that time. Therefore, it is reasonable to assume that while Solomon's Temple had an outer court (1 Kings 7:9-12) the actual practices regarding different levels of ritual impurity are unknown.

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111420/was-there-a-soreg-in-bayit-rishon.
